# Web3 constant functions require password

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I have two simple constant functions in a contract:

```
function fun1 (address A) constant returns (uint) {
    return mappingAS[A].length;
}

function fun2 (address A, uint V) constant returns (string, uint) {
    return (mappingAS[A][V], mappingBE[mappingAS[A][V]][(mappingBE[mappingAS[A][V]].length)-1].timeStamp);
}
```

(Note: the first returns a length of an array (from mapping "address => string[]") and the other one returns values from an exact position in another array (which is as well stored in a mapping "string[] => struct[]")

Now both of these constant functions seem to work in the Mist GUI (contract watch) but if I try to call them through web3:

`contractA.fun1(address).call()`

`contractA.fun2(address, position).call()`

I still have to sign those calls as transactions (with password) and a transaction hash gets returned instead.

Contract and ABI are correctly assigned:

```
var contractA = web3.eth.contract(contractABI).at(contractAddress)
```

I'm using standard Mist's geth parameters. Should I somehow change the parameters of geth?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The syntax is `contractA.fun2.call(address, position)`.  Did you try that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

`contractA.fun1.call(address)`

`contractA.fun2.call(address, position)`